# Rigify: How to parent a custom metarig bone to a bone created by rigify on rig generation

Tags: rigify

In order to rig the pupil and iris size of my eyes I want to add more controls under the basic eye controller object of rigify. The Control Bone I am talking about is called "eyes" after generating the rig.

I know how to add more control bones to a rigify rig, but I have no idea how to make it a child of the "eyes" bone after rig generation since I can't simply parent my custom bone under some eye bone in the metarig because it only exists after rig generation

Comment: Perhaps you could [create a custom meta rig](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/metarigs.html) that's just a copy of the standard rig with your pupil controller added?

Comment: @MartyFouts yeah that is what I am doing right now. and in the meta rig I add a bone to control my pupils. When generating the rig I want this particular custom bone to be parented to newly generated standard rigify eye control. I can't do this in the metarig, because the eye contorl bone does not yet exist at this point. It is generated by script and does not exist in the metarig

Comment: ah.  Then you probably need to go deeper into rigify customization than I've been. You might have to actually modify the part of the script that generates the rig from the face.super_face metarig.

Comment: @martyFouts alright, thanks anyway. I also thougth of just constraining my generated control bone to the eye control, but everytime I overwrite my rig (and i will do this quite often due to rig changes) it kills the generated constraint on my cusotm contorlb one. I read about relinking constraints but somehow it doesnt work.. maybe I am doing something wrong tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after many days of researching and posting online, I finally found a built-in way on how to approach parenting custom bones to bones that are only existing after rig generation. ... and to be honest it is super simple and I wonder why I overlooked this feature in the first place. However, this is how you do it:

1. Create a bone in the metarig (the relation of the bone doesn't really matter, because rigify will change it to your needs on rig creation, just place it where you need it to be in world space)
2. In pose mode select your newly created bone and go into bone properties tab.
3. Choose a rigify type (for example basic.super_copy)
4. In the options enable "Relink Constraints" option
5. A new text-input called "parent" appears
   [image]
6. enter the name of your target parent bone into the input
7. generate your rig
8. enjoy your new bone relation for your custom control

If I had to improve this feature I would probably relocate the text-input for the parent relation. It only appears if you enable the "Relink Constraints" option, but imo this option shouldn't be constrained to another option since one could want to change the relation of a bone on rig generation no matter if there are constraints you might want to relink or not. By now it seems like I am the only person on the web who actually used this feature, but if you ever come into the situation where you need it, I hope you found this post and can learn from this answer since the feature isn't documented at all :)